# When I click pause button it paused but when i clicked again play button , it starts the song from start

Tags: java, android

How can I start the song from where I pressed pause button, help me out am new to media in `android` and am unaware from the media properties all the buttons are working fine , but I want to start the song where from at which point I stopped it -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Button play, stop,pause;
Uri path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.chelseafc);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,path);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });



    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();

            }
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();

            }
        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer= null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have a separate button for pause

Comment: coz there was a separate default fucntion for pause , like pause()

Comment: Pause and Play/Resume should be the same button

Comment: if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())  then pause otherwise resume

Comment: @IndraKumarS let me try

Comment: @IndraKumarS thnks.. i forgot to get a length of listened song..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a start button, pause button and stop button. There is no Resume button. Also when you click start after pressing pause, media loads again and starts from beginning (length = 0). You have to seek it to the paused position and resume it :

Define a global variable :

```
 int length = 0;
```

In pause listener:

```
length=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

In resume (create a resume listener):

```
        mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

**UPDATE**

Ideally pause and resume button would be same except you would toggle on-off with changing image resource between play and pause pngs and execute relevant code with help of a boolean variable :

In pause button listener:

```
 if(play)
    {
      //paused
      play =false;
      pause.setImageResource(R.id.pause);
      length=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); 
      mediaPlayer.pause();
    }else { 
      //resumed
      play = true;
      pause.setImageResource(R.id.resume);
       mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
            mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Correct wherever necessary I typed in the editor not in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code -

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.pause();

mediaPlayer.reset();
```

I think it will help you.